# Convert a Query from SQL to Entity Framework (Group by and max)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

Hello I need to convert this SQL query to entity framework.

```
SELECT
     ValueTime, MAX(creation_time) AS creation_time, Value
FROM
     DNI
WHERE 
    ValueTime 
        BETWEEN 
            '2016-06-07 17:16:15.610' 
        AND
            '2016-06-11 17:16:15.610'
GROUP BY 
    ValueTime, Value
ORDER BY
    ValueTime ASC;
```

and to get it I am using max(x => x.creation_time) that is returning a single datetime and groupby(x => new {ValueTime, Value }) that is returning an anonymous function with only two members (ValuTime and Value), so I can't convert it to a single query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please **DON'T SHOUT AT US!** - do not write in **ALL CAPS** - it's hard to read, annoying, rude and offensive - just don't do it ! (and fix your title ASAP)

Comment: Relax. Shouting is the SQL way. There were no colour displays when sql was invented. They assumed KEYWORDS in capitals would indicate structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that using this other query I am getting the same result:

```
SELECT
   ValueTime, MAX(creation_time) AS creation_time, Value
FROM
   DNI
WHERE 
    ValueTime 
    BETWEEN 
        '2016-06-07 17:16:15.610' 
    AND
        '2016-06-11 17:16:15.610'
GROUP BY 
    ValueTime, Value
ORDER BY
    ValueTime ASC;
```

and I used this linq query:

```
ctx.DNI
    .Where(
         x => x.ValueTime >= from && x.ValueTime <= to)
    .GroupBy(
          x => new { x.ValueTime, x.Value } )
    .OrderBy(
          x => x.Key.ValueTime )
```

I was not noticing that the result is typeof `IEnumerable<IGrouping<AnonimousClass, DNI>>` that means I can iterate through the result obtaining those DNI ítems.

So i can query the result again